# Windows Azure Storage in VB: Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to run an instance of the Azure Blob Storage in the Azure Visual Studio 2010 development environment, but keep getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric.
```

The stack trace is pointing to these lines:

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient

...

CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher(Function(configName, configSetter) configSetter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(configName)))

Dim this_storage_account = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString")

...
```

I'm a little dubious about the first line as it comes from a c# interpretor output of what appears to be a common hack to get around a quirk of the CloudStorageAccount class.

DataConnectionString is set to UseDevelopmentStorage=true

Both the Development Fabric and Development Storage are running in the task bar.

I've tried creating a clean solution to see if this was a configuration issue, but am still getting the same error.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: What's the rest of the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

This was extremely dense on my part. I believe that it was because I was running the WebRole through the Visual Studio server, rather than the Development Fabric. It therefore couldn't find the Storage service.

For those that follow:

When viewing your WebRoles in the browser you should note that the functionality associated with Azure (beyond a simple web browser) will not be available unless you run them through the Debugger (F5).

Comment: You don't need to run through the debugger. But you do need to set your cloud project as the startup project, and not a standard web application.

Comment: David has the right answer in this case. I had the same issue today. You need to set the cloud project as startup and run VS12 with admin privileges (run as administrator)

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this error message it was caused by an obsolete service deployment (from the previous day) that appears to have been shut down only partially - the newly started application had a different port number. The application is in C#, but I'm quite sure it is not a language-related issue.

Simply removing the old processes using the Compute Emulator UI or "csrun /devfabric:shutdown" fixes it.